# React year picker with min max range

Tags: reactjs, datetimepicker

Is there any react year picker which will only pick a year from a given range of the year. If so, how can I do it. I have tried react-datetime. But I couldn't set the range of the year.

```
<Datetime min={1800} max={2020} dateFormat="YYYY" timeFormat={false}    onChange={(date) => this.onChangeExactYear(date)}/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `isValidDate` prop (https://github.com/arqex/react-datetime#blocking-some-dates-to-be-selected)

```
const isValidDate = current => {
    const year = current.year(); 
    return year >= 1800 && year <= 2020;
};
```